# What does bind_param() do?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

```
$resultSpendStmt = $connection->prepare(...);
$array->bind_param("sdidi", $A, $B, $C, $D, $E);
$array->execute();
$array->store_result();
$array->bind_result($F, $G, $H, $I, $J, $K);
```

I am still a little unsure what bind_param does. Can someone give me an example as to what is means?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you prepare an SQL statement, you can insert a placeholder (`?`) where a column value would go, then use `bind_param()` to **safely** substitute that placeholder for the real column's value. This prevents any possibility of an SQL injection.

[You can read more about bind_param() here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)