# SQL Code With LIKE WildCard Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

This is my code. This SQL Query works properly in phpmyadmin, it returns 2 hotels as I wanted, but in the php code, it returns all of my hotels. Why is this not working?

```
    $search_text = "%".  $search_text ."%";

    $query = "SELECT name,country,province,town FROM Hotel WHERE country LIKE ? OR province LIKE ? OR town LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? ORDER BY name DESC";

    $stmt = Database::$connection->prepare($query);

    $stmt -> bind_param('ssss',$search_text , $search_text, $search_text, $search_text);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();

    $searched = null;

    $count = 0;
    while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        $searched[$count][0] = $row[0];
        $searched[$count][1] = $row[1];
        $searched[$count][2] = $row[2];
        $searched[$count][3] = $row[3];
        $count++;
    }
    $stmt-> close();
    return $searched;
```

Comment: what's this first parameter 'ssss' about? and why 5 params but only 4 placeholders in the query?

Comment: @RobP http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php it represents 4 strings.

Comment: @RobP I count 4 params? ssss is 'string,string,string,string' as per the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish)

Comment: ah, indeed. I'm so used to PDO I'd quite forgotten the formatter part in mysqli. Thx.

Comment: As to the actual problem, you might first check the value of $search_text, which must be set somewhere prior to this code. If that were not set properly it would explain getting all your rows.

Comment: So thanks to RobP, I've found the error. SearchText was empty, because I couldn't set it properly. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your code that their set the value of $search_text it might be blank so it returns all rows .

Answer (score 0):

Only problem that I see is that you've got whitespace in your string. Try removing it.

```
$search_text = "%".$search_text."%";
```

It may also be because you need to include apostrophes.

```
$search_text = '"%'.$search_text.'%"';
```

Comment: Whitespace around concatenation `.` characters does not matter. `$str1 . $str2` equals `$str.$str2`.

Comment: Tried first one. Didn't work.
Tried second one. It return no results now.