# how i insert 1 data with 2 string? and insert into database?

Tags: mysql

i was doing a insert statement and i want 2 username become 1 data and insert into database. i no sure how to do it.

here is my php and mysql

```
$target = $_GET['user'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$targetusername = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$target' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$username=  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$direct_message_room_name ="INSERT INTO direct_message_room(`direct_message_room_name`,`user_1_id`,`user_2_id`) VALUES (('$targetusername' + ' and ' + '$username'),'$id','$target')";
```

Comment: If you want to store multiple variables in one field, you can `serialize()` an array. You should have a good reason to need to do this though. It may make your database table less effective, especially when it comes to searching and such.

Comment: i was insert 2 username is becaue it is use for direct message room name . user can view their history chat with who before

Comment: Probably then best to `serialize`

Comment: Also, you are open to sql injection with you query that inserts the `$_GET` variable.

Comment: still new in php and sql~ thx for your advise. i will learn prevent sql injection is very important.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat two strings in php like so:

```
$StringAB = $StringA . " something " . $StringB;



$target = $_GET['user'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$targetusername = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$target' ")or die(mysqli_error($connection));


$username=  mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));

$rowUserName = mysql_fetch_array($username); 
$rowTargetUserName = mysql_fetch_array($targetusername );

$room_name = $rowUserName["username"] . ' and ' . $rowTargetUserName["username"]; // Create room name (assuming both exist)
$direct_message_room_name ="INSERT INTO direct_message_room(`direct_message_room_name`,`user_1_id`,`user_2_id`) VALUES ('$room_name','$id','$target')";
```

Comment: i got an error on your `$room_name = $targetusername . ' and ' . $username; `

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in`

Comment: try $username["username"] .' and '. $targetusername["username"]

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in`

Comment: Hang on you need to fetch array. Updating anwser

Comment: i edit the `$rowUserName = mysql_fetch_array($username); 
$rowTargetUserName = mysql_fetch_array($targetusername );` into `$rowUserName = mysqli_fetch_array($username); 
$rowTargetUserName = mysqli_fetch_array($targetusername );` and it works

Comment: Great. But as stated in many comments you need to protect against injections. And make sure those usernames exist :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to have two variables in one column, you can `serialize` an array, though this is generally frowned upon unless it's for a good reason.

```
$array = array('username'=>'user1','username2'=>'user2');
$serialize = serialize($array);
```

**Gives you:**

```
a:2:{s:8:"username";s:5:"user1";s:9:"username2";s:5:"user2";}
```

Use the `unserialize()` function to return it to an array. *Wordpress* is one notable web application that stores arrays in such a way.

On a side note, you need to use bind parameter to avoid injectable sql queries:

```
// Do not do this
$target = $_GET['user'];
mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE id='$target' ")
```

Here is a reference:

[What does bind_param accomplish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish)