# jQuery AJAX: Clarification on How to Pass Variable into AJAX GET Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking at a few Stack Overflow threads in regards to implementing the jQuery ajax method:

[How to pass parameters in GET requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576548/how-to-pass-parameters-in-get-requests-with-jquery)

While this thread provides some really good info, I'm looking for clarification on whether this will actually do what I think it will do.

I have the ajax GET request within a jQuery click function:

```
//click an image
$(".img_div").click(function() {

    //get integer stored in element attribute and put it in variable
    var altCheck = $(this).find('.modal_img').attr('alt');

    //get MySQL data
    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        type: "get"
        data: { 
        ajaxid: altCheck //variable from above - is this correct? 
        }
        ....
        ....
    });
```

In **get.php**, I want the variable to be used like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = $ajaxid";
```

Essentially, I'd like to modify my SQL statement by passing a variable into the AJAX request, but I'm not sure if this is how it's done.

Comment: Not related to OP's actual question. just before passing the value. you have to sanitize your variable. Look for any potential eval statements or scripts present in the alt attribute and then pass the data. Your code  is open to sql injection at this point

Comment: I thought that, because the SQL statement is within get.php, it would be safe?

Comment: what happens with your current implementation

Comment: Nothing happens yet. I'm still trying to figure out how to implement it. But I definitely would like it to be secure, which I'm not too familiar with.

Comment: No it wont what you are doing is directly assigning the value to the sql query. In the alt attribute, I can write anything. If you don't validate the alt attribute in your php file then the code is unsafe

Comment: @coffeebot have you checked console?? does it shows something?? also talking about the security you should sanitize your data before using in query.. check this http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript use this

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'get.php',
         data: {'ajaxid':altCheck},
         type: 'post',
         dataType:'json'
        });
```

and in your get.php use

```
$ajaxid = $_POST['ajaxid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = $ajaxid";
```

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. I'll accept this when it allows me.

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned earlier in the comment. The code is unsafe at this point. To answer your original question. Yes you can pass values using data attribute in the ajax call.

quoting: arkash anjum's answer

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'get.php',
         data: {'ajaxid':altCheck},
         type: 'post',
         dataType:'json'
        });
```

and get the value in get.php like this

```
$ajaxid = $_POST['ajaxid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = $ajaxid";
```

But this means you are opening your application to injection attacks

One way of solving is to sanitize the js attributes. But still this is not a fool proof solution. What you have to use is a prepared statement in the sql query and assign the ajax value using that and then execute the statement. It will be wise to use both a sanitizer and prepared statement, to avoid xss attacks and sql injection attacks

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE screeningId = ?");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_POST['ajaxid']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

Note: I don't know php so I might be wrong with some syntax.

Reference prepared statements
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll definitely look into this

Answer (score 1):

In URL pass by giving slash as follows,

```
url: "get.php/" + altCheck;
```

and in get.php file access as $_GET['altCheck']

Remember in GET method, we need to pass data in URL.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some boilerplate..(i am using your code for example.)

**Note** : when sending data in bulk for ajax request, you should use POST method but as you mentioned you want to post data with `get` i have used `Get` else you can change type to `Post`

**quick link's :** for ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

using PDOS https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

in js :

```
$(".img_div").click(function(){    

    //get integer stored in element attribute and put it in variable
    var altCheck = $(this).find('.modal_img').attr('alt');

   // lets send data.
    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        type: "get",
        datatype : "json", 
        data:{ ajaxid: altCheck } //this is valid to use as you already have variable of name altCheck in case of string it should be in double quotes. 
        },
    success : function(data) // this will be called if ajax succeeds and data will hold the ref to your returned data if any.
    {
          // do whatever with data.
    }, error : function(data) // error handler if any error occurs (failed ajax)
    {
         // do handle error here.
    }
});
```

in PHP:

```
$value = filter_var($_REQUEST["ajaxid"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // used REQUEST So get/post request wont matter.
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("select from table where id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$value);
```

Comment: What is the "s" doing in `$stmt->bind_param("s",$value);` ?

Comment: Ah, I think this answers my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish

Comment: well you already has choosen an answer..for you query please follow this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php link