# future search of mySQL query using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search

Current Situation:

I'm in the process of building a future search box for customer information that is stored in a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database. I have the search box working, and pulling correct data. I need the results to be clickable and access links to different pages. I.E. when John Doe is searched, that name will come up below the search box half way between typing. The results (that match whatever is typed) show below the search box and changed based on characters in the box. The results are what I need to be clickable.

Working (but not completed) code for future search:

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","username","password");
$db = mysql_select_db ("database",$con);
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * from customer_table WHERE customerAddress LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{
$array[] = $row['customerAddress'];
$array[] = $row['customerName'];
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I understand this code should be [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) however I could not get the search to work that way.

Next, is the [html](/questions/tagged/html) file for the search:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Customer Search Box</title>
 <script 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote:'presearch.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.bs-example{
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
margin: 50px;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 8px;
font-size: 24px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
outline: medium none;
padding: 8px 12px;
width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
margin-top: 12px;
padding: 8px 0;
width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
background-color: #0097CF;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
.tt-suggestion p {
margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class=".col-md-6">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Customer Future Search Box <small>Company Name</small></h1>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Home</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=".col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="bs-example">
    <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
 </div></div></div></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What I've tried so far:

In an attempt to make the search results clickable (linked to different pages).

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con = mysql_connect ("192.169.197.209","azzip_admin","sXf(Z1AKZtT0");
$db = mysql_select_db ("azzip_default",$con);
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * from customer_table WHERE customerAddress LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
}
?>
<a href= <?php $array[] = $row['customerAddress'];?>
<a href= <?php $array[] = $row['customerName'];?>
<?php
}

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

That not only broke my future search, it didn't create any links.

Any help or even pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: Also, you code is very vulnerable to sql injection, please use parameters binding. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @Nicolas Although warning people about SQL injection is a good thing, w3schools is the #1 source for bad advice that leads people to create them in the first place. Please, link to anything but that.

Comment: Sorry. i didn't know about that. here is a StackOverflow question on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish

Comment: What you are looking for is called "autocomplete " and from your specs you also want ajax involved. jQuery offers this. A simple google search will provide you with many solutions.

Comment: @Nicolas I understand about the injection vulnerability, like I stated in my question, I could not get it to work without the deprecated version. Besides, not really worried about security for this.

Comment: @tadman I've heard that before. It was my understanding W3schools were like the keepers of the code, sort of speak. Like, the gold standard. I could be (very) wrong, just always figured they were behind the "rules".

Comment: @RobertRocha I understand that. I just heard it referred to as "future search" before and thought that sounded cool. That part works just fine, well, with the deprecated method. I need the results to be clickable and linked.

Comment: @Jawanaut You're not the only one to mistake w3schools for some kind of authority. They're not to be confused with [w3c](https://www.w3.org), which actually *is* an authority. w3schools is just a third-rate tech advice site that uses a similar name to dupe people. Whenever possible use the [official documentation](http://php.net/docs.php), it's significantly higher quality than what you'll find on "tutorial" sites.

Comment: @tadman Okay. I see now. Wow, that was pretty shady marketing by there part. Replacing my bookmarks with W3C rather than W3school. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: @Jawanaut have a look at this: https://github.com/bobrocha/imagebox/blob/master/app/public/js/autocomplete.js I think it might help you. I wrote it a year ago for a project I did.