# where clause not working in cakephp 3.4

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to use category listing in subcategory controller. I am trying following methods to get categories which status are 1.

```
$this->loadModel('Categories');
$query = $this->Categories->find();
$query->where(['cat_status' => 1]);
```

This is returning following output

> 'SELECT Categories.id AS `Categories__id`, Categories.cat_name AS 
>       `Categories__cat_name`, Categories.cat_status AS `Categories__cat_status` 
>       FROM categories Categories WHERE cat_status = :c0'

I don't know where it is getting:c0. Then I used another code which is giving all the list but where clause is not working.

```
$this->loadModel('Categories');
$categories = $this->Categories->find('all',[
                                            'where' => (['cat_status'=>1]),
                                            'limit' => 5,
                                            'order' => 'Categories.id DESC'
    ]);
debug($categories);
```

The output is

> SELECT Categories.id AS `Categories__id`, Categories.cat_name AS
>   `Categories__cat_name`, Categories.cat_status AS
>   `Categories__cat_status` FROM categories Categories ORDER BY
>   Categories.id DESC LIMIT 5

Please suggest a suitable way.

Comment: Does it not make more sense to put the `->where()` before running the `->find()`

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with, the context, the code required to reproduce the problem, your debugging attempts, and possible errors. That being said, what you're showing there is a totally valid SQL query with a placeholder for a bound value.

Comment: @RiggsFolly In CakePHP 3.x, `find()` returns a query (builder) object.

Comment: @ndm Ah that explains the `:c0` which would be used as a Bound Parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass conditions with query like below example.

Example

```
$categories = $this->Categories->find('all',['conditions'=>['cat_status'=>1]])->limit(5)->order(['Categories.id'=> 'DESC']);
```

Comment: it's working. I get the result but why the query is 
SELECT Categories.id AS `Categories__id`, Categories.cat_name AS `Categories__cat_name`, Categories.cat_status AS `Categories__cat_status` FROM categories Categories WHERE cat_status = :c0 ORDER BY Categories.id DESC LIMIT 5     
Can you explain what is :c0 ?

Comment: @shubham715 Its not done to allow escaping the input. It is done to allow for Bound parameters.  Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: you can read in details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426172/what-does-bind-param-accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `->first()`
to your where clause, like so :

```
$query->where(['cat_status' => 1])->first();
```