# SQL Injection: trying to avoid it but got an error

Tags: php, sql

So this is only a part of my code but the only relevant thing:

```
if ($check == 0) {     
                    $host = "localhost";
                    $user = "root";
                    $pass = "";
                    $db = "myfirstdb";
                    $connect = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
                    if ($connect->connect_error){ 
                        die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
                    } else {
                        echo "Connected successfully!";
                    }

                    //$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (firstname , lastname , phone , email , date) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :phone, :email, :date)";
                    $secure = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (firstname , lastname , phone , email , date) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :phone, :email, :date)");
                    $secure->bindParam(':fname' , $firstname);
                    $secure->bindParam(':lname' , $lastname);
                    $secure->bindParam(':phone' , $phone);
                    $secure->bindParam(':email' , $email);
                    $secure->bindParam(':date' , $date);
                    $secure->execute();
                    /*if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "New record created successfully";
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
                    }*/

                    $connect->close();
```

The problem i have is whenever i execute the code an error pops out:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\Index.php:206 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\Index.php on line 206

I'm trying to avoid the SQL injection by using this code but I'm not sure whether I understood it.

Comment: Your prepare failed, you failed to check for failure, and propagated the error onwards. specifically: mysqli doesn't support named placeholders. You're trying to use PDO semantics with a completely different library. Never **EVER** assume success with operations on an external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treats sucess as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: You don't have $db variable, you have $connect.

Comment: also I don't see where the variables you're passing in were set.

Comment: The variables were set but I didn't paste the whole code as I was thinking it wasn't relevant.

Comment: @MarcB According to  [php mysqli](http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.prepare.php) it is not PDO semantics only. Mysqli can be used like this.

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ: mysqli supports prepared statements. it does **NOT** support named placeholders. `foo=?` is ok in mysql. `foo=:bar` is not.

Comment: Ok sorry misunderstood.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you. I put "?" instead of ":foo" and it works by replacing bindParam() with bind_param and $connect instead of $db. (I also watched a w3schools tutorial to understand better the prepare() in PDO)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't preparing the statement on the correct variable.  You need to do:

```
$connect->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (firstname , lastname , phone , email , date) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :phone, :email, :date)");
```

**EDIT:**

```
  $db = "myfirstdb";
  $connect = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
```

Your *Object* is the vaiable you set as a "new class", so in this case your object is `$connect` which is a **new** `mysqli` class instance. Your original script (causing the error) was using the `$db` variable which is a *string* not an Object.

You can only `->prepare` (and use the `->` syntax) on *Objects*  .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [useyourillusiontoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248987/3536236) answer, and as Marc B pointed out in comments, the code you display is confused between `MySQLi` and `PDO`.

There are various differences, you're basically trying to fit a hexagon into a Septagon shaped hole. MySQLi uses `?` as placeholders, and PDO uses named placeholders as you have in your script.

For example your code is:

```
 $connect = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
```

This means you're using the `mysqli` DB handler, so you need to replace your `:placeholder` with `?` and then set the variables **in the order they appear in the SQL string**, such as:

```
   $secure = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 
                    (firstname , lastname , phone , email , date)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
   $secure->bind_param('sssss' , 
                      $firstname, $lastname , $phone, $email ,$date);
```

So the first `?` takes the first variable after the variable type declaration (The set of sess `sssss`), so first `?` refers to `$firstname` in this instance. The number of `?` and the number of variables given in the bind parameter **must** match.

> Note the class method is `->bind_param` for MySQLi rather than `->bindParam`.

You will need to [read up a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612251/how-to-bind-multiple-parameters-to-mysqli-query) on the general syntax differences of `MySQLi` and `PDO` and particularly about what [the first paramter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826585/3536236) on the `bind_param` means .

To use `PDO` in your script you would set your class as:

```
$connect = new PDO(...$details...);
```

I would qualify that if you can use MySQLi this does *not* guarentee you can also run PDO. They're different. You can read more about correct PDO setup in your script **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369360/how-to-properly-set-up-a-pdo-connection)**.